# MySQL Insert using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I've been trying to get a form to insert records to a MySQL database using a form, but for some reason it errors out on me and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code that processes the request:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    // database connection 

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
        $dbh -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbh -> exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

    // new data 

    $title = $_POST["txtTitle"]; 

    $description = $_POST["txtDesc"]; 

    $content = $_POST["txtContent"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblPageContent          
            SET (PageTitle, Description, PageContent) 
            VALUES (:title, :desc, :content)"; 

    try {
    $update = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
    $update->bindParam(":title",$title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindParam(":desc",$description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update->bindParam(":content",$content, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $update->execute();
    $id = $update->dbh->lastInsertId();
    $update->dbh->commit();
    echo $id;

    } catch (Exception $e) {

    echo "Data could not be updated in the database.";
    echo $e;
    exit;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use it, I end up with this:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(PageTitle, Description, PageContent) VALUES
>   ('Awards', 'This is a test', '' at line 2'

I've tried tweaking the SQL syntax, but I still can't get it to work. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Either `INSERT INTO tblPageContent (PageTitle, Description, PageContent) VALUES (:title, :desc, :content)` OR `INSERT INTO tblPageContent SET PageTitle = :title, Description = :desc, PageContent = :content`

Comment: Please don't dump code into the  comments.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Is that comment to me? If so, this question is a basic syntax error that would of been solved if the OP RTM - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html **AND** should be closed, so it is not worth creating an answer.

Comment: That's your call @Sean, but code dumps in comments are hard to read and lack the space to expound upon what you have done. YMMV ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard That may be true, but in this example I put 2 simple mysql queries,  not a complex join, or even php code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `insert` syntax is WRONG.

The correct syntax is:

```
insert into tblPageContent (pageTitle, Description, PageContent)
values (:title, :desc, :content)
```

I recommend you [have MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) at hand

Comment: Ah, that's got it. I did re-edit this from an Update page. I'll have to be more careful about that.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL, take out the `SET` before the first `(`.  You use SET in updates, not inserts.

Comment: I changed that line as you suggested but the error is still triggering.

Comment: Unless you're using some really old version of php, what you state doesn't appear to be the case.  Take [this example](http://ideone.com/jAxE1f).

Comment: @Daedalus, that might be true. I'm taking out the `->` part.